# remove date when converted from milli seconds to date

Tags: javascript, date, time

My server back end sends the time value as milliseconds (`1479515722195`). I use a conversion via a library function and get it in date as `Sat Nov 19 2016 11:35:22`. How can I separate date and time? I only need its date to be used for further processing.

```
Current value in ms : 1479515722195
Current value after conversion : Sat Nov 19 2016 11:35:22
Expected value removing time : Sat Nov 19 2016
```

Comment: `theValue.substring(0, 15)` (it should be a fixed format)

Comment: To reliably format dates, use a small library like [*fecha.js*](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha) or a big one like [*moment.js*](http://momentjs.com) if you have other things you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to stringify `Date` object and cut off the part you don't want. If you only want date, you can write

```
(new Date(1479515722195) + '').substring(0, 15);
```

It will produce string `'Sat Nov 19 2016'`.

Comment: The format of *Date.prototype.toString* is implementation dependent, so this will not necessarily return what the OP wants.

Comment: @RobG. Considering v8 and Gecko as most popular ES engines, I really couldn't find an other implementation which doesn't have this format.

Comment: The point is not whether you can find where it fails, but that there is no specification requiring any particular format. So your solution depends on convention. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

just use the native Date object and get the pieces you need independently

```
var d = new Date(1479515722195);
console.log((d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getDate() + "/" + d.getFullYear())
```

outputs

```
11/18/2016
```